# Another Linkify question

Tags: android, listview, linkify

since I am new to android programming I can't figure out to get a link into a listview.

My code to linkify is:

```
TextView textviewlink = new TextView(this);
textviewlink.setText("text I want to see"); 

TransformFilter mentionFilter = new TransformFilter() { 
public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) { 
return new String("http://test.com/"); 
} 
}; 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("."); 
String scheme = ""; 
Linkify.addLinks(textviewlink, pattern, scheme, null, mentionFilter); 

Now I want to place textviewlink into a HashMap:

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

so I add like this:

```
map.put("c1", "STATUTE");
map.put("c0", " ");
map.put("c2", textviewlink.toString()); 
mylist.add(map);
```

and then:

```
ListView listnew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvdata);
SimpleAdapter mSchedulenew = new SimpleAdapter(this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) mylist, R.layout.row, 
new String[] {"c1","c0","c2"}, new int[] {R.id.CELL1,R.id.CELLBlank, R.id.CELL2}); 
listnew.setAdapter(mSchedulenew);
```

but when I display it the link looks like:

```
android.widget.textview@43e604c0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `textviewlink.getText()` rather than `textviewlink.toString()`

`toString()` simply returns a string representation of your object, which is not the same thing as its text value.

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(); 
   HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Comment: then I got the "text i want to see" but it didn't produce a link.